# Sending FCM notification automatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created an app which reads data from google spread sheet and populates it to user. I wanted to send a notification to user whenever I add a new row. Now I go manually to FCM to send message to users that a new row is added. I wanted to know is there a way to send this notification automatically to the user?

Comment: how are you adding a new row? Through app or desktop? If through app then you need to write push notification code in the app

Comment: I am adding manually to the google sheet

Comment: You really need a back-end application to manage sending notifications to your users.